# Guice to Spring Dependency Injection

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, guice

I have a project where we are using Guice for DI on the backend layers, and Spring MVC for UI. Now I am looking to do dependency injection of Backend objects initialized with Guice into my Controllers, using Spring. Am thinking of exposing the backend objects through services, but is there an easier way? Some frameworks for doing something like this maybe??

Answer (score 0):

Is this, [guice-with-a-spring-twist](http://www.earldouglas.com/guice-with-a-spring-twist/), what you are trying to achieve?

Another possibility is the Guice based MVC library [Lime MVC](http://code.google.com/p/lime-mvc/), but it may not be production ready.